# During Paypal test, I can't reach the sandbox.paypal page

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I am beginner with wordpress. I have add the s2member plugin and my problem is that i have configured the paypal option for the paypal test phase but when I try to make a purchase sandbox refuse the password of the buyer account. I am going to try to explain you what I have done until here:

I created an account on paypal developper, I went into the deshboard and here, two account was already created:

......-buyer@gmail.com
......-facilitator@gmail.com

I went back on s2members and the first thing to do to configure the paypal option is to give my paypal account details.

The first things which is asked is my paypal merchant ID

During the test phase do i have to put my merchant ID or the merchant ID of the buyer account? if I have to put the merchant ID of the buyer account where can I find it? I've looked in the details of the accounts but there is nothing.

After they ask me my paypal email adress: here no problem

After they ask me my Paypal API username, password and signature: same question here, during the test phase do I have to put mine or do I have to put the API information of the buyer account?

For the other configuration option everything seems okay.

One last thing in the code of my paypal button I have substituted this:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

by this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Now when I try to make a purchase I am redirected on a paypal page which tell me:
Paypal cannot find this transaction.the vendor 's website has a problem. Please contact the seller to resolve this issue .

I dont know what to do and how to do.. I hope you can understand what my problem is.

Sorry for my english

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign in [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/) using the email and password of the test account created. Then follow the steps in [this link](http://www.troopwebhost.org/help.aspx?id=209) to find the Merchant ID.